# JSON.parse() merges a column only when storing it into a variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a problem with a small portion of code inside a XMLHttpRequest response function.

```
let actos_anyo = JSON.parse(this.response);
console.log(actos_anyo);
```

The URL replies with JSON information, and I noticed the first occurrence of a duplicate index is being concatenated.

For example

```
[0][0]: "9981"
[0][1]: "3"
[0][2]: "2018-01-01 00:10:00"
[0][3]: "FOO"
[0][4]: "BAR"
[0][5]: "FAZ"
[0][6]: "BAK"
[0][7]: "1"
[0][8]: "0.0000000000"
[0][9]: "0.0000000000"
[0][10]: "2018-01-01 00:31:00"
[0][11]: "2018-01-01 00:43:00"
[0][12]: "2018-01-01 00:49:00"
[0][13]: "4"

[1][0]: "9981"
[1][1]: "3"
[1][2]: "2018-01-01 00:10:00"
[1][3]: "FOO"
[1][4]: "BAR"
[1][5]: "FAZ"
[1][6]: "BAK"
[1][7]: "2"
[1][8]: "0.0000000000"
[1][9]: "0.0000000000"
[1][10]: "2018-01-01 00:25:00"
[1][11]: "2018-01-01 00:42:00"
[1][12]: "2018-01-01 00:55:00"
[1][13]: "4"

[2][0]: "9981"
[2][1]: "3"
[2][2]: "2018-01-01 00:10:00"
[2][3]: "FOO"
[2][4]: "BAR"
[2][5]: "FAZ"
[2][6]: "BAK"
[2][7]: null
[2][8]: "0.0000000000"
[2][9]: "0.0000000000"
[2][10]: "2018-01-01 00:30:00"
[2][11]: "2018-01-01 00:38:00"
[2][12]: "2018-01-01 01:06:00"
[2][13]: null
```

A single response may include several entries of this same data, just changing the index N°7. This is intended. For convenience sake we'll refer to this as a same "dataset"

However, whenever I try to console log or store it into a variable, all of the data of the index 7 is merged on the first occurrence of the same dataset, which will result in the following:

```
[0][0]: "9981"
[0][1]: "3"
[0][2]: "2018-01-01 00:10:00"
[0][3]: "FOO"
[0][4]: "BAR"
[0][5]: "FAZ"
[0][6]: "BAK"
[0][7]: "1 2 null" << this changed, this is wrong
[0][8]: "0.0000000000"
[0][9]: "0.0000000000"
[0][10]: "2018-01-01 00:31:00"
[0][11]: "2018-01-01 00:43:00"
[0][12]: "2018-01-01 00:49:00"
[0][13]: "4"

[1][0]: "9981"
[1][1]: "3"
[1][2]: "2018-01-01 00:10:00"
[1][3]: "FOO"
[1][4]: "BAR"
[1][5]: "FAZ"
[1][6]: "BAK"
[1][7]: "2"
[1][8]: "0.0000000000"
[1][9]: "0.0000000000"
[1][10]: "2018-01-01 00:25:00"
[1][11]: "2018-01-01 00:42:00"
[1][12]: "2018-01-01 00:55:00"
[1][13]: "4"

[2][0]: "9981"
[2][1]: "3"
[2][2]: "2018-01-01 00:10:00"
[2][3]: "FOO"
[2][4]: "BAR"
[2][5]: "FAZ"
[2][6]: "BAK"
[2][7]: null
[2][8]: "0.0000000000"
[2][9]: "0.0000000000"
[2][10]: "2018-01-01 00:30:00"
[2][11]: "2018-01-01 00:38:00"
[2][12]: "2018-01-01 01:06:00"
[2][13]: null
```

Testing revealed that this is NOT happening on the following scenarios:

- Outputting the JSON.parse() return value directly to console. (`console.log(JSON.parse(this.response));`)
- Attaching a debugger and processing the lines step-by-step.

Raw JSON-encoded data as requested (`this.response`). I apologize the obfuscation of sensible data.

```
[
  [
    "9981",
    "3",
    "2018-01-01 00:10:00",
    "FOO",
    "BAR",
    "FAZ",
    "BAK",
    "1",
    "0.0000000000",
    "0.0000000000",
    "2018-01-01 00:31:00",
    "2018-01-01 00:43:00",
    "2018-01-01 00:49:00",
    "4"
  ],
  [
    "9981",
    "3",
    "2018-01-01 00:10:00",
    "FOO",
    "BAR",
    "FAZ",
    "BAK",
    "2",
    "0.0000000000",
    "0.0000000000",
    "2018-01-01 00:25:00",
    "2018-01-01 00:42:00",
    "2018-01-01 00:55:00",
    "9"
  ],
  [
    "9981",
    "3",
    "2018-01-01 00:10:00",
    "FOO",
    "BAR",
    "FAZ",
    "BAK",
    null,
    "0.0000000000",
    "0.0000000000",
    "2018-01-01 00:30:00",
    "2018-01-01 00:38:00",
    "2018-01-01 01:06:00",
    null
  ]
]
```

What is happening and how can I prevent it?

If more info is needed about this please leave a comment below and I'll update the question.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where's the code where you try to do the concatenation? And what method is `JSON.encode()`? Do you mean `JSON.stringify()`?

Comment: This error does not happen in the concatenation. (It's a Array.concat() function)

Sorry if the OP implied that, I'll edit it properly.

Comment: About the title, I apologize, I mixed up with the PHP function name, I edited it.

Comment: What does the raw `this.response` look like, without parsing it?

Comment: Edited the original post, added the information requested.

Comment: I can paste that JSON into the Chrome web console, parse it, assign the parsed object it to a variable, re-stringify that new object, reparse that and assign it to yet another object, and nothing changes. No weird concatenation. Are you sure something else in your code isn't changing the data later?

Comment: What are you setting the `responseType` of the XHR to? If you're using `json`, `response` should already be a JavaScript object and you shouldn't need to run `JSON.parse()` on it.